# Probability of having ANY of (at least one of) $\{1,2,3\}$ in a random draw of $n$ numbers (without replacement) from $\{1,2,...,100\}$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

As the questions says, what is his probability?

I need to sample $n$ numbers from ${1,2,...,100}$ and find the probability of this sample of $n$ numbers containing any of${1,2,3}$?

My work so far is that we have $\binom{100}{n}$ different combinations. The possible events are:

$99*98*...*(100-n)$ contain 1
$99*98*...*(100-n)$ contain 2
$99*98*...*(100-n)$ contain 3

But I'm having trouble with how to overcome the double counting when considering those that contain ${1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}$ and ${1,2,3}$?

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  much easier to work backwards.  What's the probability that the first number is $>3$?  Given that the first isn't, what's the probability that the second is also $>3$?  And the third?  Of course, the answer you want plus the probability of the complement is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

P(At least one draw <= 3) = 1 - P(All Draws >3)

In order for all the draws to be greater than 3, you must have a number larger than 3 for your first pick, and a number larger than 3 for your second pic etc.

Since you have 100-3=97 numbers larger than 3, you have:

97*96*95*...*(97-(n-1)) ORDERED ways of doing this, just by choosing one of the 97 for the first draw, then one of the 96 for the second draw etc.

so P(All Draws > 3)= 97*96*95*...*(97-(n-1)) / 100Cn

And your answer follows

Comment: The denominator is 100*99*98*...*(100-(n-1)), not 100Cn. Some simplifications follow.

Comment: @Did Alternatively the numerator could be $97\text{C}n$

Comment: MathsQuant525 = MathsQuant ?

Comment: HAHA just seen that. Thanks for the correction. You're right